# Graph based image segmentation

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing, graph

how could I transform an image into undirected graph in order to segment it  ?I am using c++ and Opencv .
Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What people understand under "graph-based image segmentation" in computer vision is described here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_cuts_in_computer_vision. The main reference you want to look into is Boykov & Jolly 2001. The code is free on Kolmogorov's homepage.

Comment: Thank you for your answer .I am looking to use the notion of theory graph , mainly the notion of minimum spanning tree to segment a binary image. I will read the article about graph cut , many thanks .

Answer (score 0):

Not.

What would be the nodes of that graph? Presumably a set of pixels from the image. That means that the image is already segmented, which contradicts your goal of using the graph to segment the image.